# Username and password are always incorrect with custom javafx login dialog

Tags: java, if-statement, javafx, textfield, gridpane

Really don't know what do to do here? Any help on where my next move could be so that I can get this up and running would be greatly appreciated!
I am looking to roll this log in application into my next class project by using a combo box with this login screen. IF anyone has any suggestions on what im doing wrong or if my code could be written better it would be fantastic.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Pair;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import java.util.Optional;


public class LoginPassword extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Enter your username and password");



        ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("Login", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);


        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField username = new TextField();
        username.setPromptText("Username");
        PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
        password.setPromptText("Password");

        grid.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
        grid.add(username, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(password, 1, 1);


        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

        Optional<Pair<String, String>> input = dialog.showAndWait();
        System.out.println(input.get());


        if (username.equals("dom123")) {

            if (password.equals("d123")) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setHeaderText("You have been logged in");
                alert.setContentText("Welcome" + username);

                return;

            } else {
                int passwordattempts = 1;
                while (passwordattempts < 3) {
                    dialog.showAndWait();
                    passwordattempts++;
                }
            }
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Contact Admin");
            alert.showAndWait();

        } else {
            int usernameattempts = 1;
            while (usernameattempts < 3) {
                dialog.showAndWait();
                usernameattempts++;
            }
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Invalid Username");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }


    public static void main (String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
  }





**strong text**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (username.equals("dom123")) {

    if (password.equals("d123")) {
```

to

```
if(String.valueOf(username.getText()).equals("dom123")){
    if(String.valueOf(password.getText()).equals("d123")){
```

Because your username and password variables are just references to the username textfield and password textfield, not the actual value stored in them, so you need to get the text that is stored in them using getText() method.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works, however now theres some issue with getting my welcome message to appear, time to do some fiddling.

Comment: He sure cant upvote because he has 1 rep only so far.But if you include some sentence on "even with the fixed if condition your code doesnt make much sense" ... you will get my vote.

Comment: @GhostCat any recommendations or things i should be doing differently? Ive been coding for all of 6 weeks now lol, trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: Well the else part with the password and username attempts is not right imo

Comment: You should declare password and username attempts variables before you even start handling the user input, and then in the else parts just increment it by 1,and show and wait dialog, without the while loop...

Comment: Dont put more information into comments. Step back; think what makes sense, and put that information into your **answer**. I am wondering for example: his program will actually ALERT when the user entered the expected name and password. Is that really what should happen?!

Comment: Affirmative, sir.

Comment: Zeljko Thank you for the advice. @GhostCat my program will alert the user if they entered the password/username incorrectly just not validate it if its correct.

Comment: No need to do `String.valueOf`, as `TextField#getText` already returns a string.

Comment: If anyone else has an idea as to why when the user/pw is entered correctly it doesnt return the welcome response, guidance would be appreciated

Comment: I put in show and wait, but when it returns the message it says welcome textfield instead of the username?

Comment: alert.setContentText("Welcome" + username.getText());

Comment: perfect! Could you explain to me why +username wasnt working so that i can understand the concept? I wish i could +100 you, you have been a significant help.

Comment: Because username references your textfield not the actual content in it...
There are numerous methods which textfield contains (one of which is getText - which gets the current text from that textfield)... in your code editor write username and then "." it will show you many other methods and properties that textfield contains
or visit official java textfield documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html